# Testbench for simple register file

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to test my register file before connecting it to ALU.
So I wrote a testbench for my register file.

```
// 16 x 32 register file with two read, 1 write port
 module regfile(
        input  logic    clk, we3,
        input  logic    [31:0] a1, a2, a3,
        input  logic     [31:0] wd3,
        output logic    [31:0] rd1, rd2);

logic  [31:0] RAM[15:0];   //16 regsiters

assign rd1 = RAM[a1];  // asynchronous read
assign rd2 = RAM[a2];

always @(posedge clk)
 begin  // synchronous write
if (we3)
    RAM[a3] <= wd3;
 end     
 endmodule
```

and this is my testbench

```
module regfile_tb();
      logic    clk=0, we3;
      logic    [3:0] a1, a2, a3;
      logic     [31:0] wd3;
     logic    [31:0] rd1, rd2;

regfile uut(.clk(clk), .we3(we3), .a1(a1), .a2(a2), .a3(a3), .wd3(wd3), 
.rd1(rd1), .rd2(rd2));

always  #5 clk = ~clk; 
 initial begin
 a1=0;a2=0;a3=0;we3=0;wd3=0;
 #10 
    we3=1;
    a1=5;
    a2=4;
    a3=6;
    wd3=15;

#100 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

So with above conditions the testbench output rd1 and rd2 will be don't care, but when I set all the input to same number the output will work and will be same as input.
I know this sound to me the output is following the input, but the schematic doesn't show that. So what could be reason for this situation.

[image]

My schematic looks like this one ( sorry i don't have access to vivado right now)

Comment: Since we don't see the schematic you are referring to, we have no idea what your question is.

Comment: I added rough sketch of the schematic.

Answer (score -1):

a1,a2,a3 are indices in a 16 entry table so should be only 4 bits wide.

Also in your test bench set an initial a value to all inputs from the start. Everything is undefined until #2.

I do not seen an initial value for your clock. So in your simulation your clock is probably 'x' all the time. That alone should have set all your alarm bells ringing.

Make a decent clock, not a single edge.

Comment: So a1,a2,a3 should be set to 4 bit. Also, I cleared my inputs to zero. Still getting 'X' for rd1 and rd2.

can someone explain what is A3/WD3 in register file ( I know they are writing port, but how to deal with them in simulation)